# "Executable was signed with invalid entitlements" when adding code signing entitlements

Tags: objective-c, iphone, cocoa-touch

I am about to publish my first free app on the appstore. Following the instruction on the developer portal, I have added an "Entitlements.plist" file, and referenced this file in the "code signing entitlements" project setting. After I did this I can no longer test the app on my Ipod, with this error message "Executable was signed with invalid entitlements". If I remove the reference to the entitlements file, everything works fine.

I have already done this:
 - re-downloaded my provisioning profile and installed it in organizer
 - Tried making a new provisioning profile and installed that
 - unchecked "get-task-allow" in the plist-file.
 - Tried "clean all targets"

Can any of you shed any light on this one? Is this critical when publishing to the appstore? I have my distribution profile ready, but I suppose I have to solve this isssue first. I am thankful for any thoughts on this matter!

Comment: I have never used an "Entitlements.plist". What are the benefits of using one?

Comment: I have re-read the instructions, and I might have misunderstood. It seems entitlements.plist is only needed for ad-hoc distribution. Can someone else confirm this, too?

Anyway, before I got Dimitris comment I did some more research. The reason I had this problem on the ipod, seems to be that I have a "Mismatch between App ID and Bundle Identifier". I havent touched the bundle identifier in the info.plist. Could this get me rejected on the appstore, I wonder?

Comment: Just use a bundle identifier like "com.yourdomain.yourappname" that's all you need to do. And you don't need entitlements to distribute to the appstore. Just make sure you have created a AppStore distribution certificate and sign the app that that, instead of your regular development certificate.

Comment: Thanks, Dmitris! I'll leave the entitlements
 out, then:-) But im having a hard time figuring out how to make that bundle identifier. My AppID for these profiles seems to be "ZQ75CFNP3G.*". I dont know what to put for company name. Would that be my appleID? or the company/organization stored inn my apple developer personal profile. My bundle display name is "mittSnitt". Should that be in that string too? Finally, do i also have to fill out the Executable file and bundle name in info.plist? Sorry about all the question marks:-) You'll be my hero if you help me ut of this one...

Comment: I'll post it as an answer, so that you can close this question if you manage to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your company (or homepage anyway) is called for example stackoverflow.com, then it's good practice to have your app identifier: ***com.stackoverflow.myAppName***. And You generic app identifier in your certificate should be ***com.stackoverflow.****. This has to be defined in the iPhone dev centre. And then make sure to edit your app's bundle identifier in the Info.plist to reflect those changes. After you do that you can test on a device and also publish for the AppStore.

Comment: Thanks using your time on this, Dmitris. I still cant work it out though... I am trying to do as you say, but i dont understand what you mean when you say  "And You generic app identifier in your certificate should be *com.stackoverflow.**.". How do I change my certificate? Do i have to revoke it and make a new one? And then download, install in keychain, etc? Sorry for being a bit slow, man...

Comment: If you go to  the Dev Centre, to "App IDs" what does the description of the app id there read? It should read something like EUYT765TR.com.youDomain.*

Comment: I have two now. My old one reads "ZQ75CFNP3G.*" and on line two "espentokerud". After reading your advice i made a new App ID, which is also shown. The description is "ZQ75CFNP3G.com.espentokerud.mittSnitt" and on line two "mittSnittAppID".

Comment: I think i got it now. I used my new appID, the one with "ZQ75CFNP3G.com.espentokerud.mittSnitt", that is without a wildcard. In the info.plist I set "com.espentokerud.plist" for a bundle identifier. To be sure i continued using the entitlement.plist, just to get the error messages. Now that they arent coming anymore, ill take it away again. Note to others: in order to use the entitlements.plist on a local device you have to set the get-task-allow to true(checked) temporarily. Thanks for again helping me out, Dimitris!

Comment: Np :) Good luck with the approval now

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like you have accidentally set the project to use the entitlements file instead of just the distribution build.  The entitlements file should not be used when compiling against your developer certificate ie for your iPod.  It should only be used for distribution.

What you have most likely done is edit the global version of the setting (by double clicking on the project file in the groups and files section) instead of the target version.

Here is how to fix that.

1. open your project in xcode
2. under project set the active sdk and the active build configuration to whatever you use for your ipod
3. open the target tab under groups and files
4. Double click on the target you are trying to build.  Target icons look like an A made out of tools
5. scroll down to code signing and remove the code signing entitlements